# Applying stConstruct to a long table with longlat coordinates

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, statistics

I try to use "stConstruct" to convert a long table to a STIDF object.

> df.construct <- stConstruct(test.data, c("longitude", "latitude"), "time", crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))

R gives the error message below

> Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : 
>     Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: -91.41184263

There is no error when I did not specify the CRS parameter as follows

> df.construct <- stConstruct(test.data, c("longitude", "latitude"), "time"))

I searched for the possible solution online. It seems that the longitude or the latitude data is out of ranges. However, for this data set, the longitude data is around -91 and the latitude data is around 35. I don't think any of them is out of range. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to help without sample data, but as a guess: are you sure your test.data doesn't have latitude and longitude switched?